# Angular materializecss select directive gives me error

Tags: angularjs, materialize

i tried to include http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/#select and i got error in console (you can see in image). Is there any solution for this issue, here is the directive which is in angular-materialize.js

```
angular.module("ui.materialize.material_select", [])
        .directive("materialSelect", ["$compile", "$timeout", function ($compile, $timeout) {
            return {
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    if (element.is("select")) {
                        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                        function initSelect() {
                            element.siblings(".caret").remove();
                            element.material_select();
                        }
                        $timeout(initSelect);
                        if (attrs.ngModel) {
                            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, initSelect);
                        }
                        if ("watch" in attrs) {
                            scope.$watch(function () {
                                return element[0].innerHTML;
                            }, function (oldVal, newVal) {
                                if (oldVal !== newVal) {
                                    $timeout(initSelect);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }]);
```

[image]

Comment: The error is very clear: `element.is` is not a function.. Just load jQuery if you use jQuery methods.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you are trying to use jQuery methods without loading jQuery. Angular comes with lightweight jQuery-like implementation ([angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)) with limited set of methods. Those methods don't include `is` and `trigger` (and many others).

So the solution is simple: if you use jQuery methods - load jQuery before Angular.

Comment: Ok, select is working if i load jquery before angular, but that select doesnt returns me value then. You can see on github that jquery is loaded after angular and all is working there properly